# Count one value and sum the other value in Pandas- Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a pivot table where i have one indexe and two values. I want the sum of one of the value on the pivot and count of the other value on the pivot, how would I do this?

```
df = pd.read_excel("Test.xlsx", sheet_name = "Mysheet")
MyPiv = pd.pivot_table(df, index = ['weeknum'], 
                           values = ['Total Actual Cost','TB ID'],
                           aggfunc=[np.sum]))
```

so far this is what I have. I want the count of the "TB ID" and sum of "Total Actual Cost"

Comment: "How would I do this?" is never a good question here on Stack Overflow. Please see [ask].

Comment: `df.groupby([weeknum','TB ID']).agg({'value_to_sum':'sum', 'value_to_count': 'count'})`?